# C++ why adding word virtual to a function declaration has compilation error?

Tags: c++, c++20

I understand why the below code compiled without errors.

```
class Base{
public:
    int fcn(); // clause 2
};

int main() {
   Base b; // clause 1
}
```

Reason is at clause 1 no definition are needed for object b.  No compilation error.
However adding virtual to clause 2 will cause compilation error.

Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccVGJNMU.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `vtable for Base'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why?

Comment: Which standard are you asking about?

Comment: Let's say c++20 ..

Comment: Post a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: Virtual function, no destructor, no implementations. Compiler's probably trying to figure out what the vtable needs to look like and can't.

Comment: Which compilation error?

Comment: *will cause compilation error* -- Please list this error.  Also please do not list errors from Intellisense or some other third-party tool.  List the actual compiler error.

Comment: "I understand why the below code compiled without errors" It certainly doesn't, as the brackets don't match up.

Comment: Copy and run it. Then add virtual keyword to clause 2 and run it. You'll see the difference

Comment: Actually, it won't be the compiler freaking out over the vtable, it'd be the linker. Anyway, I think you're tripping over an implementation detail, but the error message would prove it..

Comment: *Copy and run it. Then add virtual keyword to clause 2 and run it. You'll see the difference* -- We don't even know what compiler you are using.  You should be doing this and posting that information here.

Comment: Please, include the **exact errors** you're getting in the question. Asking us to copy it and run it is not only lazy, it's liable to give completely different results.

Comment: As the error states, it needs a virtual table, but it has none defined, because you don't implement any of the functions.

Comment: @yapkm01 -- That is not a compiler error.  That is a linker error.  The code compiled with no errors.  If you had your own development environment, you would see that a `.o` files was created for the successful compilation.  It is the linker that is complaining.

Comment: I have attached the error.  Using c++ online compiler for this exercise. So a non virtual doesn't cause linker error while a virtual function does?

Comment: Do you mean linker error `undefined reference to vtable for Base ` define function body, i.e. `virtual int fcn() {};`  I see you are java dev where all class non static members are virtual. C++ works differ, check some C++ book or article e.g. https://ansel.braket.net/archives/555

Comment: Voted to reopen. “Needs debugging details”? Seriously? The question is about whether the code should **compile**, there’s no debugging involved.

Comment: @PeteBecker Hm .. I didn't vote to reopen this thread. Anyway tx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every non-pure `virtual` member function is always considered to be odr-used and must therefore have a definition in the program. It doesn't actually need to be called or otherwise referred to in a translation unit to be odr-used as would be the case for other (member) functions.

Comment: Terminology note: ODR => [One Definition Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition)

Comment: Why then a normal non virtual function without definition does not cause linker error?

Comment: @yapkm01: A non-virtual function is only odr-used if you actually call it (or at least take its address).

Comment: And a virtual function does not requires that it needs to be called? Why?

Comment: @yapkm01 Because the language specification says that such functions only require a definition if they are named by a (potentially-evaluated) expression. The underlying reason for this rule is that the compiler can be sure where a non-`virtual` function might be called or referred to by looking for its name and if it is not named anywhere, then one wouldn't need a definition for it. But a `virtual` function may also be called without being explicitly named anywhere.

Comment: If you don't call it in some other code, no. You could have many declaration without implementation. Compiler find implementation when it find request for this function somewhere in the code.

Comment: Without a virtual function there's no need for the book-keeping required for polymorphic  behaviour. In this case the compiler's using a Virtual Table, vtable, to provide quick look-up which function, `Base`'s or the function provided by any future derived classes that override the function.

Comment: I see .. thx guys. Let me sink it in

Comment: In short : the initialization of the vtable will automatically take the address of a non-pure virtual member function ,causing the need for a definition.

Answer (score -3):

Only one reason, I think about is, that member class function is implicitly inline. Where do you have a implementation of fcn()? If in the header file, compiler translate it like inline.
But if you add virtual, it shouldn't be inline and implementation in .h file could be problem.
Try it move to cpp...
But, as I wrote, it is only guess, because your information is very poor.

Comment: Inclining has nothing to do with this issue.